# Is thermal conductivity in a thin, malleable metal possible or practical without conducting electricity?

Tags: thermodynamics, conductors, thermal-conductivity, metals

I'm looking to be able to apply and control heat to a malleable metal, ideally a wire. Perfect conditions would be a wire that takes a controlled amount of heat (heated to) between 250-450 degrees, and fairly evenly distributes this heat along it. The application is to selectively burn solid surfaces, such as wood, at scale. First, I would like to be able to vary the shape of the wire iteratively, hence the malleability -- as I develop the ideal "branding" pattern for different pieces. But later, I want to be able to process many pieces rapidly, hence the branding/stamping.

I understand that electrically charging a high-resistance metal, like Nichrome, is the common solution for household devices such as a toaster. This may be my best bet.

However, I want to know if a cost-effective metal / heating method exists without electrifying the metal, in order to increase safety and thus application. Perhaps a solution is a heated metal surface, and pressing a copper wire to it, to bring the wire to temperature before applying it to the work piece. This feels energy inefficient, though.

I also welcome any suggestions for how to think about this differently.

Answer (score 2):

Electric heating can be safe if the voltage is low. I have an old notebook that no longer works, but its charger still has an output of 19 V. I was testing it some time ago to heat one of that steel wires used to uncloging pipes.

Even with this type of source, designed to eletronic device and not for high current, the wire could be hot enough to be not possible to hold it with the hand.

Comment: That makes sense. My thought is it may require a bit of on / off cycling to keep the temperature within a specific range, and not continually increase in heat? Or is there an asymptote/upper limit to the heat of a given wire due to electrical resistance?

Comment: Both types of control are possible. The on/off cycling has more precision, because keeps the same range of temperature with different ambient conditions.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! Do you recommend steel over copper wire? How could I calculate temperatures if I know length of wire, guage, amount of voltage and duration? Do I need to control for more variables?